# Sphinx adding paragraph tags to unordered list items

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm having an issue where Sphinx is rendering my docs to HTML with an extra `<p>` element inside list items in only one list. I am using the nature theme.

Notice the list [here](http://laurelin-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing_setup.html#system) works fine, but [this list](http://laurelin-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing_setup.html#ldaps-starttls) has extra space between list items. This is caused by extra `<p>` tags inside the `<li>` tags, but I can't figure out where those p tags are coming from.

The reStructuredText source is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ashafer01/laurelin/master/docs/testing_setup.rst).

Comment: This sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2258)

Answer (score 1):

[Inconsistent line spacing in RestructuredText document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700502/inconsistent-line-spacing-in-restructuredtext-document)

I think this might be related. I'm not sure as to how to implement it exactly. I'm more of a writer than a programmer. However it sounds like there is something thats to be modified with regards to docutils and the html4css1 writer.